# Must read line by line in pseudocode and parse the line for an input

Tags: pseudocode

I am at the end of my rope. I have been doing internet searches for tutorials and help on this simple task and after nearly a hundred different links visited, I am no closer to my answer and I'm about to have a breakdown.

All I need is to write a simple pseudocode function that takes an input file with a list of strings (book titles) with a list of prices directly next to them, and when the book title matches the user's input, it spits out the price.

Basically all I need to know is how to get the second part of the line in the file that has the price, assuming it is separated by a space or comma. But no matter what string of search characters I use in Google, no one else on the planet seems to have ever had this requirement and I'm going insane.

Comment: So, uh. What language would this be written in?  Or is Pseudocode actually a language and I've been misunderstanding a ton of questions?

Comment: Pseudo code is its own language but it doesn't run or compile. It's supposed to be a training tool or a way to write a rough draft before you use a true language. I have already been made to learn Java and Python so it's quite annoying that professors keep asking for pseudo code assessments.

Comment: Ohhh. That's weird. But I can see the value. I mean, I could write that in like 5 languages. But not pseudo. Sorry